# can't change link color in chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't change the color of my links. I have checked other SO posts and W3Schools, but it's not working. My entire CSS looks like this so far

```
div.nav{
    text-align: center;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

but my links always flash black (or red or w/e) when the page loads and then turn blue.

HMTL:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="nav">
                <nav>
                  <a href="#">stuff</a>
                  <a href="#">stuff</a>
                  <a href="#">stuff-stuff</a>
                  <a href="#">stuff</a>
                  <a href="#">stuff</a>
                  <a href="#">stuff</a>
                  <a href="#">stuffstuff</a>
                  <a href="#">stuff</a>
                  <a href="#">stuff</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My browser is Chrome and I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0 from a CDN

Comment: if you inspect a link does it have a blue color being applied to it by bootstrap? I can't remember if they declare that or not.

Comment: I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t0dov5o/) from your example and I can't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: @ShanRobertson Cool. I didn't know you could do that. And yes, it has blue being applied to it. Can I override this from my external style sheet without giving the links IDs or marking them important?

Comment: It has to do with the different states a link can be in...i'll post an answer with an added "visited" state CSS style

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black !important;
}
a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black !important;
}
```

or put your style after the link to the CDN bootstrap

Comment: `!important` shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary...and, in this case, it isn't...

Comment: i want him to check if this is working - that way we can know if he puts the style link to cdn is before or after the style tag .

Answer (score 0):

If you have visited your link it may have switched to "visisted" state. To target a hyperlink with a visited state you can call the following in CSS.

```
a:visited {
  color: black;
}
```

There are a total of four hyperlink states, click on the link below to see them: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should reference bootstrap first and then your css file

## Wrong: Your css first

```html
<style>
    div.nav {
        text-align: center;
    }

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="nav">
    <nav>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff-stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuffstuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Right: Bootstrap first

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
    div.nav {
        text-align: center;
    }

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="nav">
    <nav>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff-stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuffstuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
      <a href="#">stuff</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm even demonstrating with a live example what could be wrong. It's up to the OP to decide if the solution works for him/her

Answer (score 0):

Once the link has been clicked by the user, it becomes a "visited" link and you will need to apply a style to that `a:visited` state. Try using the below CSS.

```
div.nav{
    text-align: center;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0000;
}

a:visited {
color: #0000;
}
```